# Python finite field matrix exponentiation

Tags: python, matrix, modulo, exponentiation, arbitrary-precision

Is there a simple way to calculate (especially powers/exponetiation) with matrices whose elements are integers from finite field, or at least arbitrary integer precision matrices with support of % operator?

For example let's say we have a matrix

```
A = 1 1
    1 0
```

and want to compute something like `(A**100) % 1000`, how to achieve this?

I have tried numpy, but problem is that it uses fixed precision data types so it overflows quickly... Then I tried sympy since it supports arbitrary integer precision, but it does not seem to have support for finite fields operations (except for inverse)...

Comment: If you diagonalise the matrix, then you can exponentiate the diagonal values directly, and python's builtin `pow` function accepts a modulo optional parameter specifically for this use-case. That is, in python, `pow(x, p, m)` computes `(x ** p) % m` efficiently.

Comment: Nevermind, my previous comment only works if the eigenvalues are integers, which is rarely the case. (In the case of [[1 1] [1 0]], the eigen values are phi and 1-phi, where phi = golden ratio = (1+sqrt(5))/2)

Answer (score 0):

It might be an overkill, but [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) has everything you want (and much more). It is a python based software, but is *very* large (~1.2GB download). You can use `sage --preparse script.sage` to create a python file.

There is even SO-like QA site https://ask.sagemath.org/questions/ which is specialized to sage.

Example of your code might be:

```
m = Matrix(GF(5), [[1, 1], [1, 0]])
power = m^100
```

I have used `GF(5)` as `GF(1000)` is not a finite field. Also there are some differences, for instance the exponentiation can be done either by `x**y` or equivalently `x^y`.